# How to add more parameters to Magento2 ajax search suggestion request?

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch

I want to modify the search request (search/ajax/suggest/?q) parameters to include the below:

```
    "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "rad",
      "fields": ["name^4", "sku"],
      "type": "most_fields",
      "operator": "and",
      "minimum_should_match": 3,
      "tie_breaker": 0.0,
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "boost": 1,
      "fuzziness": "AUTO",
      "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
      "lenient": false,
      "prefix_length": 0,
      "max_expansions": 50,
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
      "cutoff_frequency": 0.01,
      "zero_terms_query": "none"
    }
  }
```

I am using AWS opensearch as my search engine. Magento version 2.4.3

Comment: Have you found tha place from where Ajax request generated

Comment: That is the challenge, I couldn't find the request sending code!

Comment: Go to the Network tab, check the call search/ajax/suggest, and then check the initiator. In that, you can find which JS triggered this call and pass the arguments.

Comment: I want to modify the parameters from server side, not from JS. Through JS magento only sends the query param(search text)